# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 10 path $.Data

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

My Response

```js
{
    "Data": {
        "DashboardData": [
            {
                "LitreM": "1500.00",
                "LitreE": "3000.00",
                "AmountM": "75000.00",
                "AmountE": "150000.00",
                "TransactionDate": "05-20-2021",
                "ItemId": 1,
                "HasMLitre": true,
                "HasELitre": true
            },
            {
                "LitreM": "1600.00",
                "LitreE": "3200.00",
                "AmountM": "64000.00",
                "AmountE": "128000.00",
                "TransactionDate": "05-20-2021",
                "ItemId": 2,
                "HasMLitre": true,
                "HasELitre": true
            },
            {
                "LitreM": "3000.00",
                "LitreE": "1500.00",
                "AmountM": "150000.00",
                "AmountE": "75000.00",
                "TransactionDate": "05-19-2021",
                "ItemId": 1,
                "HasMLitre": true,
                "HasELitre": true
            },
            {
                "LitreM": "1600.00",
                "LitreE": "1600.00",
                "AmountM": "64000.00",
                "AmountE": "64000.00",
                "TransactionDate": "05-19-2021",
                "ItemId": 2,
                "HasMLitre": true,
                "HasELitre": true
            }
        ],
        "MilkRate": [
            {
                "ItemId": 1,
                "MilkRate": "50.00"
            },
            {
                "ItemId": 2,
                "MilkRate": "40.00"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Errors": [],
    "Message": "OK",
    "StatusCode": 200
}
```

My Model class which is auto generated using POJO from JSON.

```kotlin
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Response(

    @SerializedName("Errors")
    val errors: List<Any?>? = null,

    @SerializedName("Message")
    val message: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("Data")
    val data: Data? = null,

    @SerializedName("StatusCode")
    val statusCode: Int? = null
)

data class Data(

    @SerializedName("DashboardData")
    val dashboardData: List<DashboardDataItem?>? = null,

    @SerializedName("MilkRate")
    val milkRate: List<MilkRateItem?>? = null
)

data class MilkRateItem(

    @SerializedName("MilkRate")
    val milkRate: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("ItemId")
    val itemId: Int? = null
)

data class DashboardDataItem(

    @SerializedName("HasELitre")
    val hasELitre: Boolean? = null,

    @SerializedName("HasMLitre")
    val hasMLitre: Boolean? = null,

    @SerializedName("LitreE")
    val litreE: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("AmountE")
    val amountE: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("LitreM")
    val litreM: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("AmountM")
    val amountM: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("ItemId")
    val itemId: Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("TransactionDate")
    val transactionDate: String? = null
)
```

I'm getting response but it will throw this error. I know this already asked question but there is no exact solution available for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
data class Response(
    @SerializedName("Data")
    val data: Data?,
    
    @SerializedName("Errors")
    val errors: List<String>?,
    
    @SerializedName("Message")
    val message: String?,
    
    @SerializedName("StatusCode")
    val statusCode: Int?
)
data class MilkRate(
    @SerializedName("ItemId")
    val itemId: Int?,
    
    @SerializedName("MilkRate")
    val milkRate: String?
)
data class Data(
    @SerializedName("DashboardData")
    val dashboardData: List<DashboardData>?,
    
    @SerializedName("MilkRate")
    val milkRate: List<MilkRate>?
)

data class DashboardData(
    @SerializedName("AmountE")
    val amountE: String?,
    
    @SerializedName("AmountM")
    val amountM: String?,
    
    @SerializedName("HasELitre")
    val hasELitre: Boolean?,
    
    @SerializedName("HasMLitre")
    val hasMLitre: Boolean?,
    
    @SerializedName("ItemId")
    val itemId: Int?,
    
    @SerializedName("LitreE")
    val litreE: String?,
    
    @SerializedName("LitreM")
    val litreM: String?,
    
    @SerializedName("TransactionDate")
    val transactionDate: String?
)
```